# Drupal: jquery and panel page issues

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, drupal-panels

What the heck have i done?

Could some tell me what is happening with my site please? 
I'm re-learning drupal, css and jquery - doing all as the same time is probably not the best idea, but I am stuck for now.

**this is my test: `http://surety.lfwebz.com/`**
click on the **home3** tab
scroll to bottom of page

I am working with panels so the home page is a panel page, the slideshow is in a mini panel, scroller in another mini panel and text beneath the scroller is in another mini panel and all have been placed in the panel page.

**Click** on the bulleted text "**What is Supplimental Insurance?**" and note how the scroller text background color changes - the only thing that should change is the background color of the text and paragraph to the right of it

**Click** on the bulleted text "**Do I really need Supplimental Insurance?**" now note how the entire page changes, slideshow, scroller - again the only thing that should change is the background color of the text and paragraph to the right of it

Here is in a nutshell [snippet of the code]what the jquery does for all the bullets - click list item, change background color of list item, background-color corresponding paragraph, reset bkgd-color of previous selections

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
holdLinks1 = 'li:contains("What is Supplemental Insur")';

 jQuery(holdLinks1)
            .click(function(){
                jQuery(this).css('background-color', '#C2C2C2');
                jQuery('.views-row-first').show().css('background-color', '#C2C2C2');
                jQuery('li:contains("Do I really need")').css('background-color', '#e4e4e4');
                jQuery('li:contains("What happens when I have")').css('background-color', '#e4e4e4');
                jQuery('li:contains("How do I get supple")').css('background-color', '#e4e4e4');
                jQuery('.views-row-2, .views-row-3, .views-row-4').hide();
            });
});
```

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I hit the "Post" button, it saw it - for those who are learning - my issue is, I am referencing a class that is also in various other DOM objects within my page.

For example, I only referenced **.views-row-2** when I should have referenced **[.views-row.views-row-1.views-row-odd.views-row-first]** so I can zero in on that one particular element.